# terminal download speeds really slow

Tags: 12.04

My download speed in terminal apps(`apt-get`, `wget`) is very slow. Although GUI apps such as Firefox and Chrome work fine. I have no idea why this is. Its quite a wierd problem and yes, I've tried turning it off and on again

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: this wasn't the mirror and I wasn't behind a proxy, seems to work fine now